# Cannot use css react js server side

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, webpack-style-loader, css-loader

I tried to add a lot of rules to my webpack config and nothing works..

[**My Github Sample**](https://github.com/Psyycker/react-server-side-webpack2). I wan't to use css files but I don't know what change to load css :

I tried something like:

```
{
    test: /\.css$/,
    loader: 'style!css' 
}
```

or:

```
{
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: ['css-loader', 'style-loader']
}
```

Do you have an idea?

EDIT :

This is all my webpack.config.js file :

```
const path = require("path")
```

const webpack = require("webpack")

```
module.exports = {
entry: [
    "react-hot-loader/patch",
    "webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080",
    "webpack/hot/only-dev-server",
    "./src/browser/index.js"
],
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build", "assets"),
    filename: "app.min.js",
    publicPath: "/assets/"
},
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: "babel-loader"
        },
        {
            test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg|ico)$/i,
            loaders: [
                'file-loader?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=[hash].[ext]',
                'image-webpack-loader'
            ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
        }
    ]
}

,
plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
],
resolve: {
    alias: {
        component: path.resolve(__dirname, "src", "component"),
        actions: path.resolve(__dirname, "src", "actions"),
        reducers: path.resolve(__dirname, "src", "reducers"),
        store: path.resolve(__dirname, "src", "store")
    }
},
devServer: {
    host: "localhost",
    port: 8080,
    hot: true,
    proxy: {
        "**": "http://localhost:3000"
    }
}
```

};

Ok, so I don't know why but it can build but, when I start, I have this error :

> /Users/psyycker/Documents/ReactJS/IntranetReactJS/build/server.js:68034
>           return window && document && document.all && !window.atob;
>           ^
>
> ReferenceError: window is not defined
>       at  >/Users/psyycker/Documents/ReactJS/IntranetReactJS/build/server.js:68034:2
>       at /Users/psyycker/Documents/ReactJS/IntranetReactJS/build/server.js:68023:46
>       at module.exports (/Users/psyycker/Documents/ReactJS/IntranetReactJS/build/server.js:68078:46)
>       at Object. (/Users/psyycker/Documents/ReactJS/IntranetReactJS/build/server.js:67899:38)
>       at **webpack_require** (/Users/psyycker/Documents/ReactJS/IntranetReactJS/build/server.js:20:30)
>       at Object. (/Users/psyycker/Documents/ReactJS/IntranetReactJS/build/server.js:67852:69)
>       at **webpack_require** (/Users/psyycker/Documents/ReactJS/IntranetReactJS/build/server.js:20:30)
>       at Object. (/Users/psyycker/Documents/ReactJS/IntranetReactJS/build/server.js:56338:82)
>       at **webpack_require** (/Users/psyycker/Documents/ReactJS/IntranetReactJS/build/server.js:20:30)
>       at Object. (/Users/psyycker/Documents/ReactJS/IntranetReactJS/build/server.js:56216:93)
>   [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

I updated the github repository so you can try the repo directly on your machine

Comment: Have you imported the css file in the react root file (App.jsx)?

Comment: Yes : import style from "style.css"

Comment: I can't find it in your code, in which location is it?

Comment: Oh yes indeed, this code is a working one, the question is :where do I exactly put my loader in this code ?

Answer (score 1):

I can't see it in the github repo, but if you did use it, then in your `webpack.config.js` add this:

```
module: {
    loaders: [
        ....,
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
        }
    ]
}
```

And also since I can't find a style/css loader packages in `package.json` run `npm install --save-dev style-loader css-loader`

Comment: I did exactly this and I still have Can't resolve 'style.css'....
See the EDIT of my post to see how is my config file

Comment: First if you updated your project it is not appearing on github so I can't say much about your new code. And the error you mentioned in your edited PO is because you are importing from a bad path this var `import configureStore from "store/configureStore"`, should be `import configureStore from "../store/configureStore"`

Comment: It's an alias : store: path.resolve(__dirname, "src", "store")
And yhea this project is not updated, this error is on my local repo

Comment: I've updated my repo, then you can test on your machine